# Which one is preferred Registering Observer via Singleton or via RxJava?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have a problem in which i am downloading some data in my background Service which is updating AppSingleton class which further notify the registered Observers in it.

Is Registering Observer via Singleton is preferred or that via RxJava.

AppSingleton looks like this:

```
public class AppGlobalData implements AppObservable {

    private static final AppGlobalData ourInstance = new AppGlobalData();
    private List<Customer> customerList;
    private List<AppObserver> appObservers=new ArrayList<>();

    public static synchronized AppGlobalData getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private AppGlobalData() {
    }

    @Override
    public void register(AppObserver obj) {
        appObservers.add(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregister(AppObserver obj) {
        appObservers.remove(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers() {
        for (AppObserver observer : appObservers)
            observer.update();
    }


    public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        return customerList;
    }

    public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
        this.customerList = customerList;
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is all you need to do I would avoid adding a dependency like RxJava. Use RxJava if you need its cool features like operator chaining and backpressure, but this doesn't look like the case, I don't see how this code could get any simpler with RxJava.

Comment: Agreed, But what if i use this design pattern in multi threading scenarios? Does it will cost more performance than that of using RxJava?

Comment: How do you intend to use multithreading? Do you want the observers to be run on different threads when there is an update?

Comment: When there are more than one background services running and updating AppSingleton then it will lock its instance for using it in a sync but in RxJava i think that doesn't happen.

Comment: hmm ok, maybe Rx could help you after all, but I think I need more context here, where is this sync you talk about?, what is the signature of observer.update